# Strange query when calling has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Problem: `Message` class with a `has_many :through` relationship and a `has_one` relationship both to the `User` class. Getting a strange query when I try to use the has_one relationship.**

I have a `Message` class with a has_many relationship to a `User` through `message_memberships`. Each instance of `Message` as well as having users linked to it through the `has_many through` relationship has a creator who is also a `User`.

Due to laziness I started to log the creators id in a `creator_id` column on the `Message` instance (schema below). Every time a message was created I would add the creators id to the column. Every time I wanted to reference the creator I would call `User.find(message.creator_id)`. I was looking in to creating a link between the creator column and a user but I cannot find the right implementation.

The problem I am having is with referencing the `:creator_id` column in the `has_one` relationship. I would assume something like this would work

**Message.rb**

```
has_one :creator, -> { where id: :creator_id }, class_name: 'User'
```

But the query that gets called whenever I look for message.creator is this

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."message_id" = ? AND "users"."id" = 'creator_id' LIMIT 1  [[nil, 26]]
```

I am not entirely sure where the `WHERE "users"."message_id" = ?`. Without it, it looks like the query would be fine. I have no idea how to stop it from happening.

**Schema**

```
create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "contents"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "token"
  t.integer  "creator_id"
  t.string   "link"
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Okay so removing the scope and adding a foreign key like so `has_one :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :id` results in a query that looks like this `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]`. Unfortunately the number 19 is wrong and its supplying the messages primary_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this setup:

```
class Message
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: '::User', foreign_key: :creator_id
end

class User
  has_many :authored_messages, class_name: '::Message', inverse_of: :creator
end
```

Comment: Brilliant I really like this implementation. I was also able to call message.creator using this `has_one :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :id, primary_key: :creator_id` in `Message` and a simple `belongs_to :message` in `User` but that is very messy and I prefer that in your implementation the belongs_to holds the foreign key.  Thank you